# Function to reset a sequence daily

Tags: sql-server

I need a way to reset a sequence daily. Start at 0 the increment by until the next day. I am running a Java program in a Docker cluster with a SQL Server database.

So for the 24 hours in the day, start at 0 and increment the next value. When next day comes, reset sequence to zero.

I am searching for some ways to accomplish this and some best practice to avoid a race condition. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Please be specific more specific in your question. Is this in anyway involve a table ? How are you using the sequence ? Without knowing the actual context, I can advice you to take a look at `ROW_NUMBER()`. It should solve your prloblem

Comment: Really only thing specific is I need way to increment a number, starting from 0 everyday.  I could use a DB sequence and select the nextval for they day. But I will need a way to reset the sequence to start from zero everyday.  What would be best way to reset the sequence to start at 0 every day at 12am?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a Sql Server job to run the command `ALTER SEQUENCE [sequence name] RESTART;` every night at midnight.